# Insert a Widget into another Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have googled for a long time and I could'nt find a solution to my problem.

I am trying to create a window in which you can display multiple instances of another widget, just like you can see in the picture. The widgets are supposed to be different uploads you can manage with them. This is the code I wrote and

```
self.UploadArea.addWidget(uic.loadUi('gui_files/module.ui'))
```

is supposed to open the Widget inside a QWidget called "UploadArea" it probably is coded like garbage and does not make any sense but it would be nice if you could tell me an elegant answer to my problem.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args)
        uic.loadUi('gui_files/mainWindow.ui', self)

        self.upload.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print("Test")
        self.UploadArea.addWidget(uic.loadUi('gui_files/module.ui'))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Widget and MainWindow

[image]

How it is supposed to look

[image]

Thank you for your help

Lennard

Comment: you could share the .ui

Comment: what is `UploadArea`, is a QVBoxLayout, QWidget?

Comment: UploadArea s a QWidget and These are my .ui files: 
[PiratePad](http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.8Qjj9cRhvXX/latest)

Answer (score 0):

You are close - you can create multiple instances of a `QWidget` and then add these to your QMainWindow. Here is a minimal working example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class SubWidget( QWidget ) :
    def __init__ ( self, parent = None ) :
        super( SubWidget, self ).__init__( parent )
        button = QPushButton( 'toggle' )
        checkbox = QCheckBox( 'check' )
        button.clicked.connect( checkbox.toggle )
        hLayout = QHBoxLayout( self )
        hLayout.addWidget( button )
        hLayout.addWidget( checkbox )
        self.setLayout( hLayout )

class Window( QMainWindow ) :
    def __init__ ( self, parent = None ) :
        super( Window, self ).__init__( parent )
        # loadUi( 'main-something.ui', self )
        button = QPushButton( 'add' )
        button.clicked.connect( self.add )
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout( self )
        self.vLayout.addWidget( button )
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout( self.vLayout )
        self.setCentralWidget( centralWidget )

    def add ( self ) :
        self.vLayout.addWidget( SubWidget( self ) )
        # self.vLayout.addWidget( loadUi( 'sub-something.ui', self ) )

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QApplication( [] )
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

You migth be mistaken by using `addWidget()` on a `QWidget` and not a `QLayout`. Easiest fix on that part, would be adding a layout to your widget:

```
 vLayout = QVBoxLayout ()
 UploadArea.setLayout( vLayout )
 vLayout.addWidget( loadUi( 'your_file.ui' ) )
```

please give us feedback, and if something fails, show us the traceback-print

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.
I tried your easy fix but that did not work, I tried replacing my own GUI with your SubWidget and at least python did'nt Crash but nothing Shows inside of UploadArea. And if I replace (SubWidget(self)) with (loadUi("my_.ui_File")) Python crashes as soon as I hit the button

Comment: @Schnox and what does it say when it crashes? If you don't get an error msg, execute your main in the console - you might get some error information then.